# PyCharm not inserting docstring stub for class?

Tags: python, pycharm, stub, docstring

I have the following piece of code:

```
class Note:
    def __init__(self, note=None, duration=None, start_time=None):
        self.note = note
        self.duration = duration
        self.start_time = start_time
```

I wanted to generate a docstring for the class according to the NumPy docstring style, but it doesn't autocomplete. I have chosen the NumPy format in the settings under `File | Settings | Tools | Python Integrated Tools`

The auto complete works for `def __init__()`. When I start a new line after it and type `'''` it automatically inserts this:

```
'''

Parameters
----------
note :
duration :
start_time :
'''
```

But when I do the same thing under `class Note:` it doesn't do that. I'm using PyCharm 2017.3.3

Comment: Run into same problem, shame the IDE does not support this feature

Comment: Is this still the case? I'm using the CE version of PyCharm & I cannot get it's documentation comment stub to work on classes (it's only working on functions/methods) - how has a class level auto-doc feature not been build yet!?
I feel like I'm missing something, for example, in this link, surely the 'ExampleError' class docs are auto-generated: https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_numpy.html#example-numpy

Comment: @CubeBot88 Yeah I just tried again myself and it still doesn't auto insert. I agree the example you gave was probably autogenerated, but I guess that developer may have just used some other tool or IDE. I know VS Code has a plugin for it https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=njpwerner.autodocstring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a feature request with no current due date or version:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16760

EDIT: already Fixed

Comment: It was fixed 3 month ago and is working as for now.